# calc.sty missing from latex-tools MiKTeX 2.9?

Tags: miktex2.9

I seem to be missing calc.sty which I understand should be part of the standard latex-tools package.  I am using MiKTeX 2.9 in Win10, all up-to-date (including refreshing the FN database) as of today. latex-tools shows up as a package and yet ...  Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I have calc.sty in latex.tools. You can easily check with MiKTeX package manager.

Comment: What error do you get? And with which code ?

Comment: I tried to use the package empheq that apparently uses calc.sty.  When I tried it again today (after stopping and restarting TeXworks, I did not get the error message.  Thanks to both.